# How to fetch middle 0000-00-00 records btw two date ranges

Tags: mysql, date, date-range

I hope all are doing well, i have confussion, i am fetching records from mysql table, i have 2 date ranges suppose from 1 november to 1 december, between these ranges there are records with null dates, i want to display null date records with rest of the data what query should i perform

here is the code

```
SELECT * FROM `ocdclient_dataa` WHERE date_format BETWEEN '2018-11-01' and '';
SELECT * FROM `ocdclient_dataa` WHERE date_format BETWEEN '2018-11-01' and '2018-11-30';
```

condiser it a table with records from of nov

username firstname date_format
Abdul    Xyz       2018-11-01
Abdul    Xyz       0000-00-00
Abdul    Xyz       2018-11-02
Abdul    Xyz       2018-11-06
Abdul    Xyz       2018-11-09

when i apply date between 2018-11-01 and 2018-11-09 it shows all records expence the 0000-00-00 one

i am looking forward for the answer thankz

Comment: The question is unclear and not going anywhere. Post your db schema and values.

Comment: Please put some efforts in framing a question with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`

```
SELECT * FROM `ocdclient_dataa` WHERE date_format IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `ocdclient_dataa` WHERE date_format BETWEEN '2018-11-01' and '2018-11-30'
```

That will fetch all values between that dates and all values where the date is null

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `ocdclient_dataa` WHERE date_format BETWEEN CAST('2018-11-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-11-30' AS DATE) OR date_format IS NULL;
```

I believe that should work for you :)

Comment: i want all record from 1 nov till today, also records between these dates whose dates field are empty?